# State not changing correctly after receiving props from HOC

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, react-state-management

I created a HOC to handle all the logic necessary for sockets setup + handlers and wrapped my component into it passing HOC's state at the same time. I added useEffect to the wrapped component to change it's state after it gets new props from HOC. The problem is that even if it logs these props correctly in the console, it is somehow broken. The output doesn't display even after getting props, and the loading spinner is working all the time despite the fact that the loading state is set to false from the beginning. Does anyone know what may be causing this and how can I fix this?

HOC:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect, useContext } from "react";
import SocketContext from "../../components/sockets/socketContext";
import axios from "axios";
import { SentimentOutput } from "./../../types/outputTypes";
import { TaskLoading } from "./../../types/loadingTypes";




export default function withSocketActions(HocComponent: any) {
    return (props: any) => {
        const [output, setOutput] = useState({
            score: undefined,
            label: undefined,
        });
        const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false);

        const contextProps = useContext(SocketContext);

        useEffect(() => {
            if (contextProps) {
                const { socket } = contextProps;
                socket.on("status", (data: any) => {
                    if (
                        data.message.status === "processing" ||
                        data.message.status === "pending"
                    ) {
                        setLoading(true);
                        console.log(data);
                    } else if (data.message.status === "finished") {
                        setLoading(false);
                        getOutput(data.message.task_id);
                        console.log(data);
                    }
                });
                return () => {
                    socket.off("");
                };
            }
        }, []);

        const getOutput = async (id: string) => {
            const response = await axios.get(`http://localhost:9876/result/${id}`);
            console.log("Output: ", response.data);
            setOutput(response.data);
        };

        return (
            <>
                <HocComponent props={{ ...props, output, loading }} />
            </>
        );
    };
}
```

Component:

```
import React, { useState, FormEvent, useEffect, useContext } from "react";
import axios from "axios";
import PulseLoader from "react-spinners/PulseLoader";
import { faTag, faPoll } from "@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons";
import { FontAwesomeIcon } from "@fortawesome/react-fontawesome";
import withSocketActions from "../../components/sockets/withSocketActions";

import "../../styles/containers.scss";
import "../../styles/buttons.scss";
import "../../styles/text.scss";

function SentimentInput(props: any) {
    const [input, setInput] = useState("");
    const [output, setOutput] = useState({
        score: "",
        label: "",
    });
    const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false);

    useEffect(() => {
        setOutput({ score: props.output?.score, label: props.output?.label });
        setLoading(props.loading);
        console.log("OUTPUT: ", props);
    }, [props]);

    const getHighlightColour = (label: string | undefined) => {
        if (label === "POSITIVE") return "#57A773";
        else if (label === "NEGATIVE") return "#F42C04";
        else return "transparent";
    };

    const submitInput = async (input: string) => {
        let formData = new FormData();
        formData.set("text", input);
        if (props.model) formData.set("model", props.model);
        const response = await axios.post(
            `http://localhost:9876/run/sentiment_analysis`,
            formData
        );
        console.log("RESPONSE: ", response.data.id);
    };

    const handleSubmit = async (e: FormEvent<HTMLButtonElement>) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        console.log(input);
        const result = await submitInput(input);
    };

    return (
        <div className="inputContainer">
            <div style={{ width: "100%", height: "100%", justifyContent: "center" }}>
                <textarea
                    value={input}
                    onChange={(e) => setInput(e.target.value)}
                    rows={25}
                    className={"inputArea"}
                    readOnly={loading}
                    style={{
                        boxShadow: `0 0 12px 2px ${getHighlightColour(
                            output && output.label
                        )}`,
                    }}
                    autoFocus
                    placeholder={"Insert text for evaluation"}
                />
                <button
                    className={"submitInputButton"}
                    onClick={(e) => handleSubmit(e)}
                >
                    <div className={"topButtonText"}>Evaluate</div>
                </button>
                <PulseLoader loading={loading} color={"white"} size={6} />

                {output &&
                    output.score !== undefined &&
                    output.label !== undefined &&
                    !loading && (
                        <div
                            style={{
                                marginTop: "10px",
                                display: "flex",
                                justifyContent: "center",
                            }}
                        >
                            <FontAwesomeIcon
                                icon={faTag}
                                size={"lg"}
                                color={"#f0edee"}
                                style={{ paddingRight: "5px" }}
                            />
                            <div
                                className={
                                    output && output.label === "POSITIVE"
                                        ? "outputInfo labelPositive"
                                        : "outputInfo labelNegative"
                                }
                            >
                                {output.label}
                            </div>

                            <FontAwesomeIcon
                                icon={faPoll}
                                size={"lg"}
                                color={"#f0edee"}
                                style={{ paddingRight: "5px" }}
                            />
                            <div className={"outputInfo"}>{output.score}</div>
                        </div>
                    )}
            </div>
        </div>
    );
}

export default withSocketActions(SentimentInput);
```

Comment: It would be great if you post this [sandbox](http://react.new/). Or create minimum poc there. Its lot of code going here. Sandbox would be better option. Other can check and play with there .

Comment: `<HocComponent props={{ ...props, output, loading }} />` looks to be nesting your props in a prop named `props`, i.e. `props.props.output`, etc...

Comment: @DrewReese good catch.  It should be written `<HocComponent {...props} output={output} loading={loading} />`

Answer (score 0):

> Writing @Drew's comment as an answer

`<HocComponent props={{ ...props, output, loading }} />`
looks to be nesting your props in a prop named props, i.e. props.props.output
change it to-
`<HocComponent {...props} output={output} loading={loading} />`